# dig lookup different from system lookup

Tags: networking, dns, dd-wrt

I am running dd-wrt and I configured it's dns server to resolve a few hosts inside my network.

When I use `dig` to lookup these hosts, they are resolved OK, but when I try to ping those hosts I always receive an `unknown host` error message.

For example:

```
obe:~ simao$ dig dd-wrt
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> dd-wrt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44026
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dd-wrt.                IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dd-wrt.         0   IN  A   192.168.1.1
```

But then:

```
obe:~ simao$ ping dd-wrt
ping: cannot resolve dd-wrt: Unknown host
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like a Mac OS X specific problem, after doing some googling. I found quite a few threads on forums discussing this issue. An example:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2213373

Apparently it could be because your /etc/resolv.conf has two DNS-servers configured, and dig goes through both of them to find the host 'dd-wrt', while ping gives up after using only one of the DNS-servers. Try reversing the order of your servers in resolv.conf

Comment: `dig`'s manpage states its behavior with respect to OSX's resolver libraries, specifically stating that a `dig` response can be different from OSX's normal resolving functions.   Since it's unclear what 'domain' the host 'dd-wrt' belongs to, then you might want to fully qualify the name by appending a '.' to the end:  `ping dd-wrt.`